# Error in mdpat_count[index, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, rstudio, get, missings

estoy comparando métodos de imputación y encontré en internet esta fuente de código, que busco implementar en mi base de datos (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missCompare/vignettes/misscompare.html).

Sin embargo, al llegar a la parte de missCompare::get_data, mi código da error. Adjunto lo que llevo para ver si alguien pudiese echarme una mano!

```
install.packages("ALA", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

library(ALA)
install.packages("dplyr")   
install.packages("tidyverse")  
install.packages("missCompare")
install.packages("missMethods")
library(missMethods)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("pcaMethods")
library(missCompare)

epi <- ALA::epilepsy
#generate missing values
mcar_epi <- delete_MCAR(dic_epi, 0.2, "nSeizures")

cleaned <- missCompare::clean(mcar_epi,
                              missingness_coding = -9)   

metadata <- missCompare::get_data(cleaned, matrixplot_sort = T, plot_transform = T)
sapply(cleaned, class)

# > metadata <- missCompare::get_data(cleaned,matrixplot_sort = T,plot_transform = T)
# Error in mdpat_count[index, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```